# Which is the best practice to call a method every x seconds?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, backgroundworker

I have a program that controls and communicate with a microprocessor. The program sends commands to the microprocessor and receives the feedback at the same time the command is sent showing the same in various text boxes.This is activated/fired by the command control.
I need now to implement some feedback that is not related to the command and therefore is not activated by the user, (current and temperature measurement) but is relevant the status of the machine controlled by the micro.
I do not like the idea to time the message to be sent on the micro side, I would rather receive the information and process the same every x seconds on the pc side. In this way I can also include a selector for different update intervals.
I am controlling a motor and a heater.

The question is: which is the best practice to call the relevant classes to process such messages( current and temperature), timer, new thread with timer, backgroundworker,something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Interface:** I recommend you create something like `startPoll()` and `endPoll()` inside your controller class: This is the only place, where all necessary information to avoid multiple-call, interleaving etc. are in scope.

**Implementation:** I recommend spinning off a dedicated thread: The thread pool and other built-in mechanisms are not designed for work, that has a high degree of independance from the rest of the app (such as communicating with other hardware). This thread could be started by `startPoll()` and signalled to end by `endPoll()`.

**Timer:** I definitly do NOT recommend using a timer - you go straight into parallel-call-hell, if one check takes longer than the wait for the next check (or you need plumbing code to avoid that). I recommend you calculate the ealiest next start time before you start your work cycle, then when finished `WaitOne()` on the stop signal for the remaining time.

Comment: So, your advice is to start a new thread. Correct? But then I should use a timer to time the call.

Comment: Yes. And make this thread "as private as possible" to your class, i.e. don't leak a reference to it.

Comment: The System.Threading.Timer has a Change method, that can be used to retrigger the timer after IO. This way you can prevent the "parallel-call-hell", because without periodic timer events it will not occur.

Comment: @JeffRSon ... which is what I ment with "or you need plumbing code to avoid that". In addition to that, it will run from the thread pool, which is not designed for such a task: If you use many async jobs and exhaust the thread pool, you can end up with a siutation, where the uP is not serviced in time.

Comment: @EugenRieck the discussion is becoming interesting. I would really appreciate if you can give a sample code of your method.

Answer (score 1):

I guess a timer will solve it.. But not any timer, but the one in System.Threading namespace.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Comment: Why not any timer but this specific one?

Comment: You should not use a GUI related timer, because it would block your UI when the IO operation takes some time. With the System.Threading.Timer you can simply retrigger the timer after each action. So you don't need periodic calls which may cause concurrent actions.

Answer (score 0):

Following your advices I have implemented this code:

```
        public Form1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
        timer.Interval = 5000;
        timer.Start();
        }
        private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        // I will fire the events here
         MessageBox.Show("5 seconds elapsed");
        }
```

the code is obviously working but I am not sure if this is in line with your advices.